# Assigning values to array in jquery ajax done function issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento

I'm trying to add the distances from locations in my database to an array called distances. It seems that my array is being emptied before it completes it's loop and/or the index for the loop is not reassigning a value for 'x' prior to each loop completion. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Do I need a callback function somewhere?

```
<?php if (isset($customer_id)) {?>
                        customer_id = <?=$customer_id?>;
                    <?php }?>

                    //var distances = new Array();

                        $j.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/ajax_calls/originDestinationAddress.php",
                            data: { 'vendorID': <?=$vendorId?>, 'customerID': customer_id}
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                var data= JSON.parse(data);     
                                var destination = data[0].destination;
                                console.log ('destination is ' + destination);

                                var distances = [];
                                for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){
                                console.log('the array of distances for vendor with id ' + <?=$vendorId?>);
                                    var origin = data[x].origination;
                                    console.log('origin is ' + origin);

                                    if(origin && destination){
                                        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
                                          service.getDistanceMatrix(
                                            {
                                              origins: [origin],
                                              destinations: [destination],
                                              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                                              unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
                                              avoidHighways: false,
                                              avoidTolls: false
                                            }, function(response, status){
                                                if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                                                    console.log('Error was: ' + status);
                                                  } else {
                                                    var origins = response.originAddresses;
                                                    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

                                                    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                                                      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                                                      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                                                        var miles = results[j].distance.text;
                                                        var pieces = miles.split(" ");

                                                            //$j('#'+ id + ' td.distanceDetail').text(pieces[0]);
                                                            //$j('#'+ id + ' td.distanceDetail').append('<span> ' + pieces[1] + '</span>');
                                                            console.log('currently adding ' + pieces[0] + ' to distances array with key ' + x);
                                                            distances[x]= pieces[0];
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                            });
                                }//end for length of data loop
                                console.log(distances);
                            }


                        });//end done function
```

originDestinationAddress.php (receiving all the correct headers as checked in chrome developer so shouldn't be relevant):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
require_once('/connect.php');
require_once('/app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app(); 


$vendorID = $_POST['vendorID'];
//$vendorID=13;
$customerID = $_POST['customerID'];
//$customerID=8;


//Must convert ID to match Zak's program
    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("vendor");
    if ($attr->usesSource()) {
        $vendorID= $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($vendorID);
    }   



$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerID);
$customerSchool = addslashes($customerData->getSchool());
$pieces = explode("-", $customerSchool);


//obtain origination
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT street_1, street_2, city, state, zipcode, zip4 FROM DTS_Mage_Staging.ven_ship_orig WHERE ven_id=' . $vendorID);
        $i=0;
        //echo 'SELECT street_1, street_2, city, state, zipcode, zip4 FROM DTS_Mage_Staging.ven_ship_orig WHERE ven_id=' . $vendorID;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $addressString= $row['street_1'] . ', ';
            if($row['street_2']!="" && $row['street_2']!="null")
                $addressString.= $row['street_2'] . ", ";
            $addressString.= $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . " " . $row['zipcode'];
            if($row['zip4']!="" && $row['zip4']!="null")
                $addressString.= "-" . $row['zip4'];
            $addressString.= ", USA";
            $echoArray[$i]['origination'] = $addressString;
            $i++;
        }


        //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            //$echoArray[$i]['origination']= $row['ship_city'] . "," . $row['ship_state'];
            //$i++;
        //}

//obtain destination    
if ($pieces[0] == "District Purchaser"){
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mail_city,mail_state FROM dist_comp.districts WHERE agency_name='" . $pieces[1] . "'");
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
            $echoArray[$i]['destination']= $row['mail_city']. "," . $row['mail_state'];
            $i++;
        }
}else{  
    $sql2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ship_city,ship_state FROM dist_comp.schools WHERE school_name='" . $customerSchool . "'");
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
            $echoArray[$i]['destination']= $row['ship_city']. "," . $row['ship_state'];
            $i++;
        }

            $sql3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT city,state FROM dist_comp.private_schools WHERE school_name='" . $customerSchool . "'");
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)){
                $echoArray[$i]['destination']= $row['city'] . "," . $row['state'];
                $i++;
            }
        //} 
}
echo json_encode($echoArray); 

?>
```

Console screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that is hard to read!

It looks like the curly brace that you have marked as:

```
//end for length of data loop
```

is actually the closing brace to:

```
if(origin && destination){
```

The curly brace located directly after:

```
console.log(distances);
```

is the closing brace to the data.length loop.

I think what you want to do is move  `console.log(distances)`

to the line right before the end of your .done() callback like this:

```
        }//end for length of data loop

    }
    console.log(distances);

});//end done function
```

Comment: Sorry pasting the code in here kinda messes up the formatting! Trying your suggestion now. Thanks for helping!